# There is no Session Expired notification in Vaadin 7.3.2

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm using Vaadin 7.3.2 in OSGI, all vaadin bundles are active. When server is off, there is no session expired notification in page. so could you help me please...

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="vaadin-portal" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Vaadin Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Portal Vaadin App</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin UI</description>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.MainUI</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Portal Vaadin App</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Share me your web.xml configs? did you try clicking on any of the widgets?

Comment: Firstly, you are using push notifications, second try to set your heartbeat interval to small numbers, third set closeIdleSession to true. This should help you in resolving the problem. These are just pointers to resolve the issue not the solution